# iOS Memory Warning tableView EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash in multi-view app

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I'm struggling a bit with figuring out how to properly set up my view controllers to gracefully handle memory warnings.

At the moment, I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash from a view further back in the navigation controller stack whenever the app receives a memory warning.

The bad access occurs with my table view. Here's how I'm instantiating it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    UITableView *table = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
    table.dataSource = self;
    table.delegate = self;

    self.tableView = table;
    [self.view addSubview:table];
    [table release];

    ...other stuff...
}
```

And here's my viewDidUnload:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.tableView = nil;
}
```

Upon a memory warning, viewDidUnload is called, as expected, but I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on the `self.tableView = nil` line.

Am I setting up my tableView in the wrong place? I'm not using a nib file, so should I be building it elsewhere? Am I somehow passing it off to the view controller incorrectly? etc etc

Any help would be much appreciated. I still haven't grokked the sequence of events that occurs upon a memory warning, and Level 1 Memory Warnings seem to be obnoxiously common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `release` twice on `table`; once with a *deferred* release with `autorelease` when you're creating it, and again with `[table release];` after you've added it as a subview of `self.view`. Remember, if the property for `tableView` is 'retain', then it will be retained on assignment (when assigned with dot syntax) -- and, that addSubview will retain `table` as well when you add it. So, you just need to leave the `autorelease` in there -- since that deferred release (which will be balanced out by the retain that happens when you say `self.tableView = table;`.

Comment: Yup, I saw the `autorelease` as soon as I posted the question, lol. *smacks forehead* -- Thank you, sir.

Comment: Also, I recommend just using UITableViewController -- it does a lot of the alloc and so forth of a UITableView for you.

Comment: Yeah, I used to use `UITableViewController` as a convenience. Unfortunately we now need to do enough view customization on some of our screens that I need the finer-grained control of instantiating the table view myself. Thanks again!

Comment: Question: is there an advantage to leaving the `autorelease` in there instead of `[table release]`, or is either method equally appropriate here? (Just not both)

Comment: If you remove the `autorelease` and keep the `retain`, the system cleans up the allocation for `table` without waiting for the autorelease pool block to complete. This is best if you are not going to use `table` anymore and `...other stuff...` will do lots of memory allocating.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    UITableView *table = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
    table.dataSource = self;
    table.delegate = self;

    self.tableView = table;
    [self.view addSubview:table];
    //[table release]; You have already release table with autorelease.

    ...other stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @fannheyward . You're correct. I'm just going to go with response speed for my accepted answer here.